# Wait until my FormlyFieldConfig has finished loading

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-formly

I am running into an issue where I'm trying to use UI elements before they've completely loaded, resulting in undefined exceptions.

The form is loaded in the components constructor, and then I call the initializeElements method to work with the UI elements. However, as I mentioned I'm getting null and undefined exceptions because I suspect the loadForms() method is not completely finished when I go to get the objects.

I'm new to angular, so I'm not sure what I can do here to 'wait' until the form is completely loaded. I've tried placing the methods in a few different lifecycle hooks but have not had any success.

I have my component:

```
export class UIComponent implements OnInit{
    form = new FormGroup({});
    model = {};
    fields: FormlyFieldConfig[];

    constructor(){
        this.fields = loadForm();

        this.initializeElements();
    };

    ngOnInit(){
    }; 


    initializeElements(){
        var overrides = this.form.get('Overrides'); // this is null on page load
        var firstNameObj = overrides.get('First Name'); // also null on page load
    };
}
```

My component template:

```
<form fxLayoutAlign="center center" [formGroup]="form">
    <formly-form [form]= "form" [fields]="fields" [model]="model"></formly-form>
</form>
```

The method loadForms:

```
export function loadForms(){
    return [
               {
                   'key': 'Overrides',
                   'fieldGroup': [{
                   'fieldGroupClassName': 'display-flex',
                   'fieldGroup': [{
                                     'key': 'First Name',
                                     'type': 'input',
                                     'value': 'New First Name',
                                     'templateOptions':{
                                          'label': 'First Name: '
                                      }
                                 },
                                     'key': 'Last Name',
                                     'type': 'input',
                                     'value': 'New Last Name',
                                     'templateOptions':{
                                          'label': 'Last Name: '
                                     }
                                 }]
                    }]
               }
          ]
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look to lifecycles: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

If you use `loadForms()` in your `constructor()` method, it won't wait the view to load. For this, if you want to make sure your view finished loading, use `ngAfterViewInit()`.

Please, if it is possible, don't load your data or call methods on the constructor, use `ngOnInit`, `ngAfterViewInit()` or any of the lifecycle hooks listed on the docs above as needed.

I don't know if you used them, in case you tried with `ngAfterViewInit()` and it didn't work try setting an `*ngIf=fields` on your `<form>` tag

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you could create an observable

```
export class UIComponent implements OnInit{
    form = new FormGroup({});
    model = {};
    overrides: any;
    firstNameObj: string = '';
    fields: FormlyFieldConfig[];

    constructor(){
    };

    ngOnInit(){
        loadForm().subscribe(
        response => {
           this.fields = response;
           this.initializeElements();
        }
    }; 


    initializeElements(){
        overrides = this.form.get('Overrides'); // this is null on page load
        firstNameObj = overrides.get('First Name'); // also null on page load
    };
}
```

then your export function would look something similar to this. I assume this is in its own file so there might be a little discrepancy to how this should be. but if this is going to be changed from a function to http service call, the observable should stay the same.

```
export function loadForms (): Observable<any> => {
  return new Observable<any>(observer =>{
    observer.next([
      {
        'key': 'Overrides',
        'fieldGroup': [{
          'fieldGroupClassName': 'display-flex',
          'fieldGroup': [{
            'key': 'First Name',
            'type': 'input',
            'value': 'New First Name',
            'templateOptions':{
            'label': 'First Name: '
            }
          },
          {
            'key': 'Last Name',
            'type': 'input',
            'value': 'New Last Name',
            'templateOptions':{
              'label': 'Last Name: '
            }
          }]
        }]
      }
  ]);
}
```